# How to get your site trusted by AV?

Tags: download, exe, norton

I want to make an exe file available to download from my website, but when I do a test download, Norton deletes the file without any option to keep it. Presumably most AV does the same thing, so nobody is ever going to be able to download it.

Wrapping the exe in a zip seems to make the exe completely invisible to Norton, so that is one approach, but it just adds an extra step for users to go through. And I have downloaded exe files from other sites, so it is certainly possible.

Would signing the exe help? What other factors affect my site's apparent lack of trustworthiness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Signing your EXE is probably the best way to go... As far as "trusting" a website goes, I can't speak for Norton but I know that McAfee has user feedback mechanisms for rating sites, and that's what their products use to filter bad actors on the web.

Comment: Probably worth signing the exe to stop Windows itself complaining. Shame a certificate costs so much (as one website put it, they are only multiplying 2 large numbers). I wondered if Norton would take account of the signature and trust the file as a result, but the zip route is probably more reliable.

Answer (score 1):

Putting the executable in a zip file is indeed the way to go. Norton is extreme pain, but most browsers and/or anti-virus applications will at least warn the user when he attempts to download an executable. It is more important to instil confidence in your users than to make life easy for them, and if they see any kind of warning message they are likely to pull the plug.

Comment: Thanks, I will probably do that. It isn't too bad because the installer is all a standalone exe so the user doesn't need to extract it before running it.